# My image is not switching to mobile format. Is my code wrong somewhere?

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

This is the problem i am facing.
The images do not switch from one another when resizing the window.
I have 6 different formats for 3 different devices:

- 320x340 & 640x680 (Mobile)
- 870x340 & 1740x680 (Tablette)
- 1600x340 & 3200x680 (Desktop)

I get the switch between desktop and tablette, but i never get the mobile format.
I can't figure out which part of the code is wrong.
I am an absolute noob when it comes to coding.
Can anyone help?
Many thanks!

```
<style>
    
    .universHeroContainer {
        background-image: url('[imagePath]Attachment/LandingPage/2020/07/03/new/U1-FR-small-320x340_FR.jpg[imageHash]');
        }
        
        @media
        only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
        only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
        only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
        only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
        only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
        only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 
    
      /* Small screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */
        .universHeroContainer {
        background-image: url('[imagePath]Attachment/LandingPage/2020/07/03/new/U1-FR-small-640x680_FR.jpg[imageHash]');
        }
    }
    
    
        @media only screen and (min-width: 440px) {
          /* Small screen, non-retina */
            .universHeroContainer {
            background-image: url('[imagePath]Attachment/LandingPage/2020/07/03/new/U1-FR-middle-870x340_FR2.jpg[imageHash]');
            }
        }
    
        @media
        only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 440px),
        only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 440px),
        only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 440px),
        only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 440px),
        only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 440px),
        only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 440px) { 
    
      /* Small screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */
        .universHeroContainer {
        background-image: url('[imagePath]Attachment/LandingPage/2020/07/03/new/U1-FR-middle-1740x680_FR.jpg[imageHash]');
        }
    }
        
    @media only screen and (min-width: 880px) {
    
      /* Small screen, non-retina */
        .universHeroContainer {
        background-image: url('[imagePath]Attachment/LandingPage/2020/07/03/new/U1-FR-large-1600x340_FR2.jpg[imageHash]');
        }
    
    }
    
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 880px),
    only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 880px),
    only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 880px),
    only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 880px),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 880px),
    only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 880px) { 
    
      /* Small screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */
        .universHeroContainer {
        background-image: url('[imagePath]Attachment/LandingPage/2020/07/03/new/U1-FR-large-3200x680_FR_2.jpg[imageHash]');
        }
    }
        
        
        .univers-title {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .universHeroContainer {
        position: relative;
        top: -20px;
        margin-top: -5px;
        margin-bottom: -25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 340px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .universHeroContainer > p {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        color: #000000;
    }
    
    .universHeroContainer > p:nth-child(1) {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
        letter-spacing: 0.2em; 
    }
    
    .universHeroContainer > p:nth-child(2) {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 880px) {
        .universHeroContainer {
            background-position: center top;
        }
        
        
        .imgDepartment-bg { 
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
        }
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
        .universHeroContainer {
            margin-bottom: -30px;
        }
        
        .rowContainer.no-pad{
            max-width: 100%!important;
        }
        }
    
    </style>
```

Comment: write the query for 400px after the query for 800 px

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Do i duplicate the query for 400px or do i move it after the query for 800px? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Your welcome. Remeber CSS means Cascade StyleSheet ;)

Comment: I seem to be doing something wrong because i still cannot get it to work :(

Comment: @Sfili_81 could you give me an example of how it should look like? Grazie mille!

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Please proved us a working example maybe using jsfiddle

Comment: Here is the example:

Comment: https://www.bongenie-grieder.ch/fr/homepagetest-2

Comment: Its the banner image that is not switching to mobile when resizing the screen. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: It's not switching becautse its take this css _@media
 only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
 only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
 only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
 only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
 only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
 only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {_

Comment: Oh ok! What should i change it to?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out. I guess coding isn't for me :(